# `torch.cuda.is_available()` returns false on Ubuntu with GTX 1070 mobile

Tags: python, ubuntu, pytorch, anaconda

I'm trying to set up my laptop to run Pytorch with CUDA support on an Anaconda environment. However, when I install pytorch and cudatoolkit and run `torch.cuda.is_available()` on a ipynb notebook cell, the returned value is False.

My system info is:

- GPU: GTX 1070 Max-Q
- OS: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
- Graphics Driver: 535.129.03
- Python version: 3.11.5
- My `nvidia-smi` output:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 535.129.03             Driver Version: 535.129.03   CUDA Version: 12.2     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070 ...    Off | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   39C    P8               8W /  90W |      6MiB /  8192MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1979      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            4MiB |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Here's what I've tried so far:
The output of `torch.cuda.is_available()` persists being False after trying the installation of pytorch with these different commands (each in different environments created with `conda create --name env_name python=3.11`):

- `conda install pytorch cudatoolkit -c pytorch`
- `conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.8 -c pytorch -c nvidia`
- `pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118` from [pytorch documentation](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) for CUDA 11.8.
- `pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio` from pytorch documentation for CUDA 12.1 as well.

None of these returns `torch.cuda.is_available()` as True and I'm having a hard time understanding if it's a problem with the different versions, the version of CUDA that my GPU supports or if the problem is the version of Pytorch that I'm trying to install.

From the [Nvidia CUDA Release Notes](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html) and my `nvidia-smi` output, I understand that I should be able to run CUDA 12.1 or 11.8, but maybe my understanding is wrong.

I would appreciate any support, thanks!

Comment: You have activated the venv (`conda activate env_name`)?

Comment: Note if you're using `conda` you can install packages into it using `pip`, but the command is `pip install torch==2.0.0` (or whatever version you want) not `pip3` which will install into the system python.